# Using element in vector as index in array?

Tags: c++, vector, random, timing

I'm writing code that randomly generates a vector of indices, fetches a random one, then uses that index to fetch another index, and so on. However, my code seems to repeat a cycle of indices. Here is my full code:

```
vector<uint16_t>* genBuffer() {
    vector<uint16_t>* buffer = new vector<uint16_t>(256);
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, 255);
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        (*buffer)[i] = distr(gen);
    }
    shuffle(buffer->begin(), buffer->end(), gen);
    return buffer;
}

double timeAccess(vector<uint16_t>* buff, uint64_t buffSize) {
    struct timespec start, stop;
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, 255);
    auto index = distr(gen);
    auto nextIndex = (*buff)[index];
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i <= buffSize; i++) {
        cout << nextIndex << endl;
        nextIndex = (*buff)[nextIndex];
    }    
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &stop);
    double time_taken = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) - (double)(stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);
    double avgTime = time_taken/buffSize;
    return avgTime;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "Please enter only one numerical argument." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    uint64_t buffSize = atoi(argv[1]);
    auto randBuff = genBuffer();
    auto timeTaken = timeAccess(randBuff, buffSize);
    cout << "Average time per buffer read = " << timeTaken << " ns" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an example run with an argument of 25:

```
35
218
157
9
4
214
225
246
123
92
195
114
200
33
138
13
17
35
218
157
9
4
214
225
246
123
```

As you can see, the pattern eventually repeats, although it shouldn't do that.

This code is part of a cache benchmark I was asked to write for class. Here is the full code for anyone willing to try:

https://github.com/aabagdi/CacheBenchmark

As well, I'm trying to time the average time per read in ns. Am I doing that correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ah, I forgot, sorry about that! Will do

Comment: I have no idea what the clock has to do with any of this. The cycle problem, however, is obvious. Consider a most-trivial scenario where `(*buff)[0] = 3`, and `(*buff)[3] = 0`.

Comment: The clock is there because I was asked to time the loop.

Comment: Ah, I see, but in my code I randomise the array and shuffle it, so that occurrence shouldn't be so common, right?

Comment: @ness64 regarding your last edit, you don't seem to understand what  [mcve] means, please read that linked article again, and [edit] your question accordingly!

Comment: It can easily still happen if the shuffle produces a scenario like I described, which it certainly can, and in your case, certainly *did*. Also, I assume the dump of `nextIndex` is intended for debugging. Otherwise the *vast* majority of your time-spent is going to be console IO.

Comment: Why shouldnt it repeat? You use random to pick the first element. You then follow the links in the table. You need to show the code that generates the table, it clearly has a loop in it

Comment: @WhozCraig Well, the purpose of this code is, in the words of my professor, "fool the prefetcher and compiler into exposing gaps in memory performance", so he basically told us to write inefficient code.

Comment: @pm100 I added my full code

Comment: That makes sense from the assignment perspective. However, this is logistics. In your sample data you have what looks like an 17-element loop, but its the same problem I described earlier with a much-more-trivial 2-element loop. Once you fall into a loop none of the elements *outside* of the loop will ever be reached. Make no mistake; you *want* a loop, but it needs to be the *entire* sequence that is involved. If you were to chain indexes (a leads to b, leads to c, etc.) the *last* index (whatever it is) should lead back to the first. You're just doing that by mistake with a much shorter loop

Comment: You are debugging two steps (generate data and traverse data) at once. Bad idea. Take it one step at a time. You should look at what is generated by `genBuffer()` in addition to what is generated by `timeAccess()`. *(Hint: also output `index` so you can traverse by hand.)* If the output produced by `timeAccess()` is correct given what `genBuffer()` produced, then focus on `genBuffer()` and remove `timeAccess()` from your [mre]. Otherwise, pick one result from `genBuffer()` that reproduces the problem, and (in your example) hardcode this result instead of using randomness in `genBuffer()`.

Answer (score 2):

The generation of your traversal vector is flawed, and can easily generate loops. An example of what you're actually trying to generate for maximal traversal is similar to an interesting (albeit outdated) interview question concerning dropping a stack of bus tickets, each of which has a starting city, ending city, and as a city *pair* is unique among all others.

Consider holding four tickets, each of which goes from some city Sn to some other city Sm.

```
S4->S2
S1->S5
S3->S4
S5->S3
```

the proper order can be thought of like this:

```
S1->S5
    S5->S3
        S3->S4
            S4->S2
```

The only difference here is that you need to get back from S2 to S1 if needed, since you don't really know where you're starting from. By adding one faux ticket, `S2->S1`, you can produce a maximal loop.

```
S1->S5
^   S5->S3
|       S3->S4
|           S4->S2
|               S2->S1-\
|                      /
\----------------------
```

Now it doesn't matter where you start from; eventually you'll hit every city and be back where you started (to do it again if you want).

One way to do that is by building a pairing sequence, then patching in the final return-to-origin as a last step. First, `n` indexes, build an index array of values 0..(n-1).

```
// build index vector and shuffle
std::vector<uint16_t> idx(n);
std::iota(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);
std::mt19937 gen{ std::random_device{}() };
std::shuffle(idx.begin(), idx.end(), gen);
```

This is the rock on which we will build our church. We're going to traverse this random ordered sequence, and store the `i+1`'th index in the `i`'th slot of our final result. Like this:

```
// build chain
std::vector<uint16_t> result(n);
for (size_t i=0; i<(n-1); ++i)    
    result[idx[i]] = idx[i+1];
```

Finally, the last step is to link the last element of this chain to the initial element of the chain (wherever it is).

```
// set loop
result[idx[n-1]] = idx[0];
```

That's it. Now, it doesn't matter where you start in `result`, it will eventually lead to touching each index before returning to your starting point where it loops (maximally).

The full `genBuffer` looks like this:

```
std::vector<uint16_t> genBuffer(size_t n) 
{
    // build index vector and shuffle
    std::vector<uint16_t> idx(n);
    std::iota(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);
    std::mt19937 gen{ std::random_device{}() };
    std::shuffle(idx.begin(), idx.end(), gen);

    // build chain
    std::vector<uint16_t> result(n);
    for (size_t i=0; i<(n-1); ++i)    
        result[idx[i]] = idx[i+1];

    // set loop
    result[idx[n-1]] = idx[0];

    return result;
}
```

To prove this actually works, a simple test harness to generate a 32-element chain with a maximal loop.

```
int main() 
{
    auto randBuff = genBuffer(32);

    // pick some random starting point.
    std::mt19937 gen{ std::random_device{}() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> dist(0, randBuff.size()-1);
    auto idx = dist(gen);

    for (size_t i=0; i<randBuff.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << idx << " -> " << randBuff[idx] << '\n';
        idx = randBuff[idx];
    }
}
```

**Output** (varies, obviously)

```
19 -> 10
10 -> 21
21 -> 12
12 -> 22
22 -> 28
28 -> 6
6 -> 16
16 -> 1
1 -> 7
7 -> 3
3 -> 27
27 -> 8
8 -> 14
14 -> 15
15 -> 17
17 -> 2
2 -> 9
9 -> 25
25 -> 31
31 -> 5
5 -> 18
18 -> 13
13 -> 29
29 -> 24
24 -> 26
26 -> 4
4 -> 20
20 -> 11
11 -> 0
0 -> 30
30 -> 23
23 -> 19
```

Note the *last* production leads to the first production.

In summary, your index vector generation is susceptible to loops. You want a loop, but only *one* and should be maximal. Doing what I showed above can give you that.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of thoughts

- your generate function will generate the same data each time since you do not seed your (p)rng
- You randomly pick an entry and then follow the links, why wouldnt there be a loop? WHy not simply print them out and see if there is a loop.

I mean your generate function can create in the list

```
1,2,3,0
```

Thats a loop